# Redefine Citation Command

Tags: macros, citing

How can I redefine the citation command `\citep` and `\citet` in order to include the page number, which is given in the bib-file, in the citation.

Example:

`"The circumstances do not pose a threat, at least right now." \citep{Cite-Key}`

> "The circumstances do not pose a threat, at least right now." (AuthorX, 2017, p.45)

or

`According to \citet{Cite-Key} the circumstances can be neglected for the time being.`

> According to AuthorX (2017, p.45) the circumstances can be neglected for the time being.

Comment: Typically page elements specific to a citation is added using the optional argument, like `\cite[..]{...}`.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Plus the data is not likely to be available for the cite commands from the data anyway. Perhaps bilateral can access it from the bib file, normal bibtex most likely cannot, so redefining citet and citep cannot solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> How can I redefine the citation commands `\citep` and `\citet` ...

No redefinition is needed! Assuming the entry of interest has key `author:2017`, you would just write

```
\citet[p.~45]{author:2017}
\citep[p.~45]{author:2017}
```

to mention "p. 45" along with the citation call-outs.

Comment: I entered the page number in the bibfile already, so I was wondering whether I could use the page number from there.... is that possible?

Comment: @thebilly - *How* did you enter the page number?

Comment: I added added the page number in the designated row for that below author, journal and so on.

Comment: @thebilly - What do you mean by "designated row"? Do you mean something like `pages = "5-17"`? Is the entry type `@article`? Please advise.

Comment: yes just like that, and yes it is an article, sometimes also a book.

Comment: @thebilly - AFAICT, the whole point of creating a citation call-out of the form `AuthorX (2017, p. 45)` is to make it easier for readers who wish to look up the citation to find the citation, esp. in a longish article or book. Do think through what exactly you'd be telling your readers if you were to simply regurgitate the information from the `pages` field in the citation call-out? Your readers would surely think that such "information" was both clutter an pointless. Don't do it! Instead, write something like `\citet[p.~45]{author:2017}` -- exactly as I suggested in my answer...